# how to convert scatter chart into line chart in d3 version 3

Tags: d3.js

I have implemented one scatter chart using d3.js. I want to convert this chart to line chart, but i am not able to do so. I have tried to follow ( http://embed.plnkr.co/wJDcZmkEzXaLVhuLZmcQ/ ) but it didn't helped me.

This is the code for scatter chart.

```
var data = [{"buildName":"otfa_R5-10_a1","build":"Build 1","value":"19628"},{"buildName":"otfa_R5-91_a1","build":"Build 2","value":"19628"},{"buildName":"otfa_R5-9_a1","build":"Build 3","value":"19628"}]
  var yValues = [], responseData = [];
  data.map(function(key) {
      var test = [];
      test[0] = key.build;
      test[1] = key.value;
      responseData.push(test);
      yValues = key.value;
  })

  var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 15,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 60
      },
      width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(responseData.map(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      }))
      .rangePoints([0, width], 0.5)

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([5000,20000])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var chart = d3.select(divId)
      .append('svg:svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr('class', 'chart')

    var colors = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([5, 20])
      .range(['#4577bc', '#4577bc'])

    var main = chart.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('class', 'main')

    // draw the x axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient('bottom');

    main.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .attr('class', 'main axis date')
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")  
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)" );

    // draw the y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient('left');

    main.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
      .attr('class', 'main axis date')
      .call(yAxis);

      var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
      .attr("class", "tooltip")             
      .style("opacity", 0);

    var g = main.append("svg:g");

    g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
      .data(responseData)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style('stroke', function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
      })
      .style('fill', function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
      })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {    
          d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "#fff8ee");   
          div.transition()      
              .duration(200)        
              .style("opacity", 2.9);       
          div   .html((d[1]))   
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")       
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");  
          })                    
      .on("mouseout", function(d) { 
          d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#4577bc");  
          div.transition()      
              .duration(500)        
              .style("opacity", 0); 
      });
```

How we can add a line connecting these points ?

Please help me !!

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. Please help me to convert it to line chart or draw a new chart for the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a line to your existing chart, just add it using [path generators](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#path-data-generators).

Line generator:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
  .y(function (d) { return y(d[1]); });
```

Append the line to the svg:

```
g.append('path').classed('line', true)
  .style( { fill: 'none', 'stroke': 'steelblue'} )
  .attr('d', line(responseData));
```

Snippet with the above code included and a few CSS styles to make it look better:

```js
var data = [{"buildName":"otfa_R5-10_a1","build":"Build 1","value":"19628"},{"buildName":"otfa_R5-91_a1","build":"Build 2","value":"10628"},{"buildName":"otfa_R5-9_a1","build":"Build 3","value":"17628"}]
  var yValues = [], responseData = [];
  data.map(function(key) {
      var test = [];
      test[0] = key.build;
      test[1] = key.value;
      responseData.push(test);
      yValues = key.value;
  })

  var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 15,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 60
      },
      width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(responseData.map(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      }))
      .rangePoints([0, width], 0.5)

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([5000,20000])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var chart = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg:svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr('class', 'chart')

    var colors = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([5, 20])
      .range(['#4577bc', '#4577bc'])

    var main = chart.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('class', 'main')

    // draw the x axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient('bottom');

    main.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .attr('class', 'main axis date')
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")  
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)" );

    // draw the y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient('left');

    main.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
      .attr('class', 'main axis date')
      .call(yAxis);

      var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
      .attr("class", "tooltip")             
      .style("opacity", 0);

    var g = main.append("svg:g");
    
    g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
      .data(responseData)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style('stroke', function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
      })
      .style('fill', function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
      })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {    
          d3.select(this).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "#fff8ee");   
          div.transition()      
              .duration(200)        
              .style("opacity", 2.9);       
          div   .html((d[1]))   
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+4) + "px")       
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");  
          })                    
      .on("mouseout", function(d) { 
          d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#4577bc");  
          div.transition()      
              .duration(500)        
              .style("opacity", 0); 
      });
      
      
 var line = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
  .y(function (d) { return y(d[1]); });
    
  g.append('path').classed('line', true)
    .style( { fill: 'none', 'stroke': 'steelblue'} )
    .attr('d', line(responseData));
```

```css
path.domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}
.axis text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help.